# How to show exact result in 3 table query in sql

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with my `sql` commands. I tried many ways on how to query this 3 tables.

```
         post table
===========================
id | username | post | date
```

With 5 data rows inside

```
    profile table
======================
username | bio | name
```

Also it has 5 data inside

```
     like table
====================
post_id  | username
```

This like table only 1 data inside

This is my database design for my simple social media project. If I click the like button the `post.id` and `username` will be inserted to the `like table`. I wanted to count the `like.post_id` in order to get the number of like of every post.

I tried :

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(like.post_id) AS post_like 
FROM like,post,profile 
WHERE post.username=profile.username AND like.post_id=post.id`
```

The problem with this is that only one data is fetch. I wanted to fetch 5 data inside post and profile and post_like on his post match.

Can someone help me about this one ?

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause!  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

That said, I would approach this using a correlated subquery for the count:

```
SELECT p.*, pr.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM like l
        WHERE l.post_id = p.post_id
       ) AS post_like
FROM post p JOIN
     profile pr
     ON p.username = pr.id  -- this is really strange
```

The `JOIN` condition on `post` and `profile` looks incorrect, but I've left it in.

The correlated subquery avoids an aggregation in the outer query, which is usually a performance winner.  You want an index on `likes(user_id)` -- but you would want that anyway.

Comment: What do you mean about p.* and pr.* it gives error on my command.

Comment: @RonCajan . . . Those are well defined table aliases in this query.  I don't see a problem.

Comment: I used this query "SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like JOIN post ON like.post_id = post.id) AS post_like FROM post JOIN profile ON post.username = profile.username" it shows all my post but the post_like shows on every row. I wanted to show it only inline into the post with id.

Comment: @RonCajan . . . That doesn't look like the query in this answer.

Comment: I modified the answer because it return sql error. @Gordon